# Find the sum of the $\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\binom{m}{k}(1-p)^k\cdot p^{m-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, binomial-coefficients

Let $0<p<1$,Find the sum
$$\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\binom{m}{k}(1-p)^k\cdot p^{m-k}$$

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: ${1 \over 1 - p}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64022/the-limit-of-binomial-distributed-random-variable

Comment: [What does $\binom{-n}{k}$ mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fact that for $|x|<1, \:k\geqslant0$
$$
\frac1{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\binom{m}{k}x^{m-k}
$$
which can be proved by differentiating $k$ time on both sides of following
$$
\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}x^m
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\binom{m}{k}(1-p)^k\cdot p^{m-k}&=(1-p)^k\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\binom{m}{k}p^{m-k}
\\
&=(1-p)^k\frac1{(1-p)^{k+1}}
\\
&=\frac1{1-p}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

In [this ansswer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647), it is shown that
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{m}{k}
&=\binom{m}{m-k}\\
&=(-1)^{m-k}\binom{-k-1}{m-k}
\end{align}
$$
Plug this into
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=k}^\infty\binom{m}{k}(1-p)^kp^{m-k}
&=\sum_{m=k}^\infty(-1)^{m-k}\binom{-k-1}{m-k}(1-p)^kp^{m-k}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\binom{-k-1}{m}(1-p)^kp^m\\
&=(1-p)^k(1-p)^{-k-1}\\[4pt]
&=\frac1{1-p}
\end{align}
$$
which converges for $\left|p\right|\lt1$.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a coin which lands heads up with probability $p$, and you keep flipping it until it lands **tails-up** $k+1$ times, recording the number of flips this takes as $X$. Then:

$$\mathbb{P}(X=m+1)=\mathbb{P}(k \text{ tails in the first } m \text{ flips, then another tails})=\binom{m}{k}(1-p)^{k+1}p^{m-k}$$

Given that $k+1\le X < \infty$ almost surely, we see that

$$1=\sum_{m\ge k}\mathbb{P}(X=m+1)=\sum_{m=k}^{\infty}\binom{m}{k}(1-p)^{k+1}\cdot p^{m-k}$$

which gives the desired sum as $\frac{1}{1-p}$

**Appendix:** $X < \infty \text{ a.s.}$

Proof: $\mathbb{P}(X\ge a)=\mathbb{P}(\le k \text{ tails in first }a \text{ flips})=\sum_{0\le j\le k} \binom{a}{j}p^{a-j}(1-p)^j=O(a^kp^a)\to 0 \text{ as } a \to \infty$